# can you use a primitive or inbuild data types as a method in golang

Tags: go

i wanna know if we are able to use inbuild data types as a method for a func in golang, cause whenever I use it as such, it shows an error

Comment: Can you include a code sample?

Answer (score 3):

You can define methods on built-in types by first wrapping them with your own types, like this:

```
type MyInteger int

func (my MyInteger) Tell() {
    fmt.Println("I'm MyInteger with value", my)
}

func main() {
    var my MyInteger = 42
    my.Tell()
}
```

You can try this [on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/D-_0gHsR3Xk), it will print:

```
I'm MyInteger with value 42
```

This can be useful if you want to make a built-in type implement an interface. For example, here's how `MyInteger` would implement the `fmt.Stringer` interface:

```
type MyInteger int

func (my MyInteger) String() string {
    return "MyInteger " + strconv.Itoa(int(my))
}

func main() {
    var my MyInteger = 42
    fmt.Println(my)
}
```

Comment: thax i guess there is no way of using the raw in build data types, which is kinda frustrating as i always had thought that  golang was all about  'ease of programming' . do u by any chace know y it is so, as we are unable to use the raw in build type other then by creating our own data type ?

Comment: Go is not all about ease of programming. Go is about making sure your code is maintainable. Changing the behavior of built-in types is not maintainable, so Go does not support that, but wrapping with your own types is easy. If there's a specific task you're trying to accomplish and don't know how, consider creating a new question with a minimal, reproducible example